# Is there a way to reload the .XCompose file in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, gnome3, compose-key, ibus

I am currently custumizing my .XCompose file in Fedora 29 Workstation (with the default GNOME 3, Wayland, etc). It seems that it does follow the rules I add to the ~/.XCompose file, but if I make changes to it then they are only noticed after I log out and log back in again. Is there something I can do to make the changes take effect immediately?

I tried running `ibus restart` on the terminal but it didn't seem to work. Actually, doing that broke the compose-key functionality completely and I had to restart the session again to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

About ~/.XCompose:

> This file is read by libX11 whenever a new X program is started. So, your existing terminals won't be able to type these new characters, but any new terminals you launch will.

So, there's no way, unfortunately.

Comment: This isn't the same behavior I am encountering though. I have to restart the whole desktop session. Even relaunching programs is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Under Fedora 30 (Gnome 3.30, X11), reloading Gnome Shell seems to work for me:

1. Launch *quick run* with `<Alt> + <F2>`
2. Type `r` then `<Enter>`
3. Wait for the shell to reload

Somehow it even makes things work in some already running programs, which makes no sense to me...

Comment: Unfortunately this option is not available under wayland. In that case you must log out to reload the shell